# Reputation Graph Footer mis-aligned in Internet Explorer

Tags: bug, internet-explorer-11

In Internet Explorer 11, the dates below the reputation graph footers are mis-aligned. This is happening for all sites across the network.

[image: Mis-aligned rep-graph months]

[image: Mis-aligned rep-graph years]

Internet Explorer Version: 11.0.9600.19236